# Getting products description in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a website with two stores let's say English and Greek. So in the Admin Panel on the upper left corner there is also the **Default value**. I want to the the description of the products of the **Default values** with `store id = 0` so I'm using the following code:

```
$store_id = 0;
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                   ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

 foreach ($collection as $product) {
            echo "Name".$product->getName()."<br />";
            echo "Description ".$product->getDescription()."<br />";
    }
```

I manage to get the name of the name of all the products but I can't get the description.

Any help would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine on my local test environment.

Comment: Same here.... it does not throw any error but I can't see any results back.. :-(

Comment: It's showing the results for Description in my local.

Comment: Try reindexing?

Comment: didn't work ...